# To make an API call with an oAuth token

Tags: ruby, oauth

I want to make oAuth request in Ruby. I skimmed some examples but none of them used `oauth_token_secret and oauth_token` to make a request, they only used `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` to get `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token`. But I already have `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token`.

For example, this one I tried to use

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
                               {
                                 :site=> "https://www.google.com",
                                 :scheme=> :header,
                                 :http_method=> :post,
                                 :request_token_path => "/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken",
                                 :access_token_path => "/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken",
                                 :authorize_path=> "/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
                                 :signature_method=>"RSA-SHA1"},
                               # :private_key_file=>PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY
                               )

request_token = consumer.get_request_token()

puts "Visit the following URL, log in if you need to, and authorize the app"
puts request_token.authorize_url
puts "When you've authorized that token, enter the verifier code you are assigned:"

verifier = gets.strip

puts "Converting request token into access token..."

access_token=request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => verifier)

puts "access_token.token --> #{access_token.token}" # But I initially have it
puts "access_token.secret --> #{access_token.secret}" # But I initially have it
```

In my case, there are 4 secret keys:

```
consumer_key = "anonymous"
consumer_secret = "anonymous"
oauth_token_secret = "fdsfdsfdfdsfds"
oauth_token = "fdsfdsfdfdsfdsdsdsdsdsdsds"
```

So what I need to do is, to make a API request to the certain url with some additional get parameters and oAuth token and to get the answer.

How do I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'
```

You need to get your access_token (`OAuth::AccessToken`).

```
# Initialisation based on string values:
consumer_key = 'AVff2raXvhMUxFnif06g'
consumer_secret = 'u0zg77R1bQqbzutAusJYmTxqeUpWVt7U2TjWlzbVZkA'
access_token = 'R1bQqbzYm0zg77tAusJzbVZkAVt7U2T'
access_token_secret = 'sVbVZkAt7U2TjWlJYmTxqR1bQqbzutAuWzeUpu0zg77'

@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {:site=>'http://my.site'})
accesstoken = OAuth::AccessToken.new(@consumer, access_token, access_token_secret)
```

Once you have your `OAuth::AccessToken` object, you do :

```
json_response = accesstoken.get('/photos.xml')
# or
json_response = accesstoken.post(url, params_hash)
```

etc.

The response is a json object. To read it, you can do :

```
response = JSON.parse(json_response.body)
# which is a hash
# you just access content like
id = response["id"]
```

Comment: I don't need to take OAuth::AccessToken since I already have oauth_secret and oauth_token.

Comment: @AlanDert I know. Use the object you get here: `access_token=request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => verifier)`

Comment: What is verifier? Can you give the complete example please? Be aware, that Typhoeus has an error, I can't use it.

Comment: How do I do that for oAuth2? Please show me again.I saw the examples at GitHub, but the constructor of AccessToken was different from the one in the first version.